# Possible issues with multiple solution files for the same set of projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

*Is there a list of all (or nearly all) possible issues that could stem from maintaining multiple solution files for the same set of projects?* The only reason for doing so is different versions of Visual Studio.

I'm aware of the glaring issue where new projects are added in one solution file, that haven't been synced to the other. What are some others?

*disclaimer: my current company is still entrenched using VS10, for mainly political reasons. so please, save the preaching about the need for having a single solution and how this is not the optimal "solution".*

Comment: 2012 will open and use 2010 sln files without breaking them (up to a certain point)

Comment: (up to a certain point) is the stickler. 2010 w/ sp1 can't open "our" .slns converted to 2012.

Comment: What about _not_ converting the solution to 2012, just opening it in 2012?

Comment: @CharlieBrown that's what i'm currently doing, if i understand you correctly. i opened the "old" solution, converted projects and saved the solution with a different name — so to not affect the old solution.

Comment: In 2012, you have the option of opening the 2010 sln, but NOT converting the projects. It should interop just fine with no changes. We do it all the time.

Comment: More info at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/28/round-tripping-with-visual-studio-11.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done all the time, for the most part it is perfectly fine other than what you mentioned, any files added would have to be added to all of the projects.  However, I would recommend you go with a make file of sorts, [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) is a very robust version but there are plenty of others.  The way they work is basically, you write one script that defines how the project is to be made, then the end-user runs CMake.exe on it.  It will take that script and generate the proper solution and project files for your entire project in the version of VS you want, it also supports generation of types like XCode and Eclipse solutions etc so it is very multi-platform.